Driving a piezo actuator using push pull stage made of TRIACs

This is how I'm going about it, but I couldn't find transistors that'd do the trick since my supply voltage was 50 volts so I decided to use BTA26 600 TRIAC which was cheaply and quickly available, able to switch even higher voltages that piezo is capable of handling.I am using an Arduino to generate the signal driving the TRIAC, switching each on and off in turn. The forward gate voltage of TRIAC is 1.5 volts .
The actuator I'm using is the TDK Powerhap 1919 :
https://datasheet.octopart.com/Z63000Z2910Z1Z43-TDK-datasheet-140091427.pdf
If I'm understanding correctly, my piezo can be considered a capacitor when operating much lower than resonance, this setup seems adequate for sourcing and sinking current through a capacitor .
This is the basic code I'm running with pin 6 and 7 connected to the gates of the two TRIACs.
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(7, LOW);
  delay(10);
}

Doesn't seem to be driving anything, I'm hearing something near the resonance frequency of the TRIAC but not the square wave I'm sending .

How about using transistors like MJE340/MJE350, as shown in this question: Help me understand this high voltage amplifier circuit for driving a piezo actuator?

Triacs are not well suited for this application. They don't turn off while substantial current is flowing. You should also provide a schematic showing how you've connected the parts exactly.

P.S. I can imagine ways you could connect it that would quite easily destroy the Arduino and maybe your computer if you have it plugged in to the USB, or destroy the triacs.

@SpehroPefhany can you elaborate more on why TRIACs are not suitable? Also you're right, I destroyed my arduino somehow by connecting the digital outputs to gate of one of the switches while I removed the ground from another. It seems current somehow went through the gate and into the arduino through the logic pins and totally destroyed it

@SpehroPefhany how I connected is pretty simple, now I've connected the digital out pins from arduino to each of the gates, one terminal of triac 1 is connected to the supply, the other to actuator which is connected to ground from the other end. The former connection is also connected to one terminal of triac 2 while the other is connected to ground. So when triac 2 is on, in my head both the plates of the actuator are connected to ground.

@Vrisk Your description is not unambiguous. There are two interpretations of triac 1, one of which immediately destroys the Arduino, the other of which may do so randomly.  That's why we use schematics. Anyway, forget about using triacs. They don't switch off and even if they did you would still need to voltage shift the gate signal.
